# pygame.surface.get_at((x, y)) not returning correct pixel data

Tags: pygame, pixel, pygame-surface

I have a simple program which allows the user to draw white pixels in a black box. when the user clicks the blue button I want my program to go through all the pixels  in the draw box and add the pixel data to an array for later use in another project. However, it only returns black for each pixel even if the user has drawn an image on there.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

# set up the screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
pygame.display.set_caption("drawTest")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# goes through the screen data and reads the pixel data
def GetPixelDataOfDrawScreen():
    for i in range(200):
        for j in range(200):
            if(i > 49 and i < 150):
                if(j > 49 and j < 150):

                    # gets the red, green, blue and alpha (RGBA) components of the pixel
                    pixelColor = screen.get_at((i, j))
                    print(i, pixelColor[0])

                    if(pixelColor[0] == 255):
                        pixelDataOfDrawBox.append(255)
                    else:
                        pixelDataOfDrawBox.append(0)

                    # dosen't work
    print(pixelDataOfDrawBox)

pixelDataOfDrawBox = []
rects = []

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # adds close button to screen
                sys.exit()

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))                                                    

    # gets the mouse position
    mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    # draw drawing box
    boxX = 50
    boxY = 50
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), (boxX, boxY, 100, 100))

    if(mouseX >= boxX and mouseX <= boxX + 100 - 2): # check if drawing
        if(mouseY >= boxY and mouseY <= boxY + 100 - 2):
            if(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]):
                rects.append([mouseX, mouseY, 2, 2])

    # blue button
    bButtonX = 100
    bButtonY = 150
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), (bButtonX, bButtonY, 50, 20))

    if(mouseX >= bButtonX and mouseX <= bButtonX + 50): # check if pressed
        if(mouseY >= bButtonY and mouseY <= bButtonY + 20):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 180), (bButtonX, bButtonY, 50, 20))
            if(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]):
                GetPixelDataOfDrawScreen()

    # red button
    rButtonX = 50
    rButtonY = 150
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (rButtonX, rButtonY, 50, 20))

    if(mouseX >= rButtonX and mouseX <= rButtonX + 50):
        if(mouseY >= rButtonY and mouseY <= rButtonY + 20):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (180, 0, 0), (rButtonX, rButtonY, 50, 20))

    # draw the rects
    for r in rects:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you check the pixels after the `screen` surface gets cleared and before you draw the white rects/pixels. The drawing box area is still black at this moment. A quick fix would be to call `GetPixelDataOfDrawScreen` below the code that draws the rects:

```
# draw the rects
for r in rects:
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), (r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3]))

if(mouseX >= bButtonX and mouseX <= bButtonX + 50): # check if pressed
    if(mouseY >= bButtonY and mouseY <= bButtonY + 20):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 180), (bButtonX, bButtonY, 50, 20))
        if(pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]):
            GetPixelDataOfDrawScreen()

pygame.display.flip()
clock.tick(60)
```

Also, the program can be simplified. You could probably just serialize the `rects` list with the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) or `pickle` modules, or create a separate surface for the drawing area and then just save it with [`pygame.image.save`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.save).

Here's an example in which I draw onto another surface instead of the screen. You can save it with `pygame.image.save` and load it with `pygame.image.load` (press <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>O</kbd>). I also recommend creating [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects for the box and the buttons because they have useful collision detection methods like `collidepoint`:

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

box_surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
box = box_surface.get_rect(topleft=(50, 50))
blue_button = pygame.Rect(100, 150, 50, 20)
red_button = pygame.Rect(50, 150, 50, 20)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_s:  # Press s to save the image.
                pygame.image.save(box_surface, 'box.png')
            elif event.key == pygame.K_o:  # Press o to load the image.
                box_surface = pygame.image.load('box.png').convert()

    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]:
        # Adjust the mouse positions because the box is positioned at (100, 100).
        mouse_x, mouse_y = mouse_pos[0]-box.x, mouse_pos[1]-box.y
        pygame.draw.rect(box_surface, (255, 255, 255), [mouse_x, mouse_y, 2, 2])

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(box_surface, box)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), blue_button)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), red_button)
    if red_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (180, 0, 0), red_button)
    if blue_button.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 180), blue_button)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Also thanks for the improved code, i'm still a bit new to pygame so i didn't know how to simplify it. The original purpose for this was for an AI and ML test, so the user would draw a number or an image and the AI would guess what the user drew, so saving it as an image and doing separate things with it works a lot better i think.